# AWS Lambda event not conforming to APIGatewayProxyEventV2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my code I am expected a APIGatewayProxyEventV2 event.

Among other things it should have:

```
event.rawPath
```

When logging the event I don't see this but instead:

```
event.path
event.requestContext.path
```

So I suspect I'm on some old version. I would like to configure aws lambda / api gateway proxy integration to use V2. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems while deploying the API Gateway using the AWS CLI, AWS CloudFormation, or an SDK, you have set `payloadFormatVersion` value to `1.0`. That's why API Gateway is sending version `1.0` specific payload to your Lambda function.

If you don't specify a payload format version, the AWS Management Console uses the latest version by default.

You can read more about this here [Payload format version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format).